# All Observer event calling one method! Confused!

Tags: magento2, event-observer

Calling **EventObserver** `$observer->getEvent()` multiple times.

I am using a single execute(EventObserver $observer) to call

```
$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
$productdel = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
$payment = $observer->getEvent()->getPayment();
$this->productUpdate($product);    //catalog_product_save_after event
$this->saleOrderComplete($payment);   //sales_order_payment_place_end event calling productUpdate()
$this->productDelete($productdel);   //catalog_product_delete_after event calling productUpdate() why?
```

All my other events seem to call same function.

Why?

Answer (score 1):

Solved.I created different observers with a single `execute()` in each class